# Node web application was started in Linux, but web service access prompts no server data

Tags: linux, iptables

Recently, I rented a Linux server, and on that, I developed a Node.js web program. I have opened the port, but I still can't access this web service.

iptables setting is below:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

iptables status is below:

```
[root@VAM_60_90_centos firewalld]# systemctl status iptables.service
* iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/user/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-03-02 22:41:10 CST; 11min ago
 Main PID: 22884 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 02 22:41:10 VM_60_90_centos systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Mar 02 22:41:10 VM_60_90_centos iptables.init[22884]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: [ OK ]
Mar 02 22:41:10 VM_60_90_centos systemd[1]: Started IPv4 firewall with iptables.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What's the linux version? Maybe selinux is not configured to allow HTTP port 8080. Issue `sestatus` on a terminal and see if it's enabled.

Comment: linux version is centos 7.0, And i changed firewalld to iptables. And when i executed sestatus, it shows selinux is disabled. Does that mean there is no problems with selinux?

Comment: a little bit awkward, really! But thinks to @hering for re-editing. I will pay attention to the format of question!